# Association Rule Mining using the library mlxtend

Tags: python

I run Association Rule Mining using the library `mlxtend` on the clinical dataset with the dimension `(23144, 32)`.

Unfortunately, after around 50mins, I mostly got a message "kernel died...", so after checking I've realized that it runs out of memory.

I also tried with Google Cloud (trial version 300$ free, using up to 15GB), then the problem is the same.

Questions:

1) Could the above amount of data be considered as the big data for the association rule algorithm? I think it is still small, why does it consume a lot of memory?

2) I also tried with FPGrowth algorithm which is faster than Apriori 5x, then the problem is still the same, is there any way to overcome this?

3) I think the current python libraries of the Association Rule algorithm have no good support for relatively large data? Am I right?

### Python Code

```
dataset01 = pd.read_csv('dataset_origin.csv')

transaction = TransactionEncoder()

transaction_fit = transaction.fit(dataset01.to_numpy().tolist()).transform(dataset01.to_numpy().tolist())
# transaction_fit
array([[False,  True,  True, ...,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, ...,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, ...,  True, False,  True],
        ...,
       [ True, False,  True, ...,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, ...,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, ...,  True, False,  True]])

df_rf = pd.DataFrame(transaction_fit, columns=transaction.columns_)

frequent_itemsets = fpgrowth(df_rf, min_support=0.3, use_colnames=True)
```

The program gets stuck on this code line

Answer (score 0):

I've just resolved the exactly same problem with the `apriori()` function.

1) When you try to get the frequent itemsets from a sparse dataframe (in your case `df_rf`) with too many columns and few rows you occur to be in a high dimensionality problem. In my case, my sparse dataframes had very few rows but a many columns (`(3, 72)` and `(27, 500)`). If you are interested in the topic you can find many papers about association rules mining applied to high dimensional data.

2) I guess that the choice between the two algorithms doesn't help when you have high dimensional data.

3) By looking the `mlxtend` documentation, I couldn't find any support related to this problem. However, if you set a `min_support` higher than `0.3` (try different values) your code will finish running.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your comments

Sorry, I made a mistake on question. My dataset is 23144 rows and 32 columns. I think that it still gets involved in association rule mining of high-dimensional dataset.

Another approach which I've also tried is that finding closed/maximal frequent item sets and finally, I got the same problem.

Then, I gradually increased min-support up to 0.6, then the algorithm runs well, but I think it is not good because we can miss valuable rules (information loss)

still looking for the solution